# $A×x×B=C$ What is x?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$$\left(\begin{matrix}-1&0\\1&1\\\end{matrix}\right)\cdot X\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\0&1\\\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&-1\\\end{matrix}\right)$$
How can I solve this matrix equation?

Comment: Do you know what matrix inverses are?

Comment: yes I know it, and can Inverses help me?

Comment: What happens if you multiply the equation $AXB=C$ by $A^{-1}$?

Comment: well $A*A^{-1}=E$

Comment: Yes, but what if you actually multiply the whole equation by $A^{-1}$? For example, for any matrix $D$, you know that if $A=B$, then $DA = DB$, right?

Comment: Unrelated, but using `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}` will automatically include correctly-sized parentheses; use `bmatrix` for a matrix between brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

You have a matrix equation:
$$
AXB=C
$$
with $ A$ and $ B$ invertible matrices, so you can find:
$$
A^{-1}AXBB^{-1}=X=A^{-1}CB^{-1}$$

---

$$
A^{-1}CB^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0\\1&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\1&-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: yes... but I suppose that the OP refers to matrices in $M(2,\mathbb{R})$ ...would otherwise specified the context.

Comment: Will be the answer ($\begin{matrix}0&-1\\1&-3\\\end{matrix})$?

Comment: It seems that you have some mistake.. i've added to my answer.

Comment: thank you so much Emilio.:)